# Whats the best way to put multiple maps (as a value) for another map?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a requirement where i have multiple maps and values for each map is different like..

```
Map<String,Boolean> a = new HashMap <String,Boolean>();
Map<String,HashSet<String>> b= new HashMap <String,HashSet<String>>();
Map<String,String> c = new HashMap <String,String>();
Map<String,ArrayList<String>> d = new HashMap <String,ArrayList<String>>();
```

Now i want all these map (a,b,c d) to be used as value of another map (say e) which need to be returned back as the service response.

Could anyone suggest how these different types of Maps can be handled?

EDIT: Basically, I want to put maps a, b, c, d into e (be it map or a list or anything that's suited best) and send as a response to the calling method

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  A `Map` should generally speaking have values all of the same type, or at least the same interface.  It seems like this should use a class, not a map.

Comment: A class with all these different types? An example would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting?  `class Foo { private Map<String, Boolean> a; private Map<String, Set<String>> b; ... public Map<String, Boolean> getA() { return a; } ...}` A perfectly normal class.

Comment: Basically, I want to put maps a, b, c, d into e (be it map or a list or anything that's suited best) and send as a response to the calling method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but it sounds like you want to have a map of these maps.

```
Map<SomeKey, Map<String,?>> e;
```

With this, you can do:

```
e.put(key1, a);
e.put(key2, b);
e.put(key3, c);
e.put(key4, d);
```

Then, you can get them out like this:

```
Map<String, ?> stringMap = e.get(key1);
Object value = stringMap.get("some string");
```

And then cast the final values.

Comment: Who said `getKey()` returns the same value every call? ;)

Comment: `String getKey() { return String.valueOf(i++); }`. Jokes aside, I changed it for clarity.